# Attempted to Perform an Unauthorized Operation C# ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to create an ASP .NET web application on a remote webserver which will check to see if a folder exists in the webserver, create it if it does not, check to see if a file exists within that folder, create it if it does not, and then write and append that file accordingly with things input into the webpage.

Doing such a thing requires the ability to create directories, create files, and read/write files. Naturally, Full Control would encompass everything that I need to accomplish, and for the sake of this specific task, there is no downside to giving myself Full Control. The directory I am trying to gain access to is the parent of the current webpage, as the webpage that is creating the directory is in /root/Pages/currentPage.aspx, whereas the directory that I want to create is /root/Files/fileToBeCreated.txt.

Currently, my security code looks like the following:

```
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo("..");

    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"Network Service", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

However it is throwing an error, stating that I attempted to perform an unauthorized operation on this line:

```
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

I have tried making use of identity impersonate="true", which also does not work and throws several increasingly complicated errors related to my Web.config file. Furthermore, I'm uncertain which username or password I would assign it.

Whenever I try running with a network user other than "Network Service", it throws the same error, which is that "Some or all identity references could not be translated." Based on this, I know that "Network Service" is a valid user, but I am not sure how to assign permissions.

I'll reiterate that the webserver is remote and I have no direct access to it, otherwise this would be a breeze, but all permissions being set must be done programatically via a webserver.

Please let me know if I'm missing any required information, and thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, websites run using the "Network Service" account on the server. If this is the case for your remote server, you are trying to grant "Network Service" new permissions but you are using it to do so. Basically, it cannot grant itself permission it does not have.

You can refer to this if you wish to change the windows account that your website runs under. Read carefully the Security Notes and recommendations on this page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc1xthy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I see, so in short, there's no way for me to actually give permissions to the website as it is now? Because I am designing the website, but am not actually the website / server administrator, so I suppose I will have to contact them to obtain permissions, then?